# What are the Redhat function's to replace the SUSE functions?

Tags: linux, operating-system, redhat, suse

OS (Operating System) is using SUSE functions checkproc(), starproc(), killproc()

Unfortunately, Redhat got rid of this and these functions need to be replaced with Redhat functions.
In this case, what are the exact functions (in Redhat) to replace the SUSE functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the RHEL functions as a replacement to SUSE.
Here is the quick link to go-through the same.

https://www.peerspot.com/products/comparisons/red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel_vs_suse-linux-enterprise